# L'Hospital's rule proof review

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $f,g$ be real valued functions defined on $(a,b)$ and $f,g $ be differentiable on $(a,b)$ such that $g'\ne 0$ on $(a,b)$. If $\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}\to A$, as $t\to a$.
If
$1) f(t)\to0, g(t)\to 0$ as $t\to a$.  **Or** 
2) $g(t)\to \infty$ as $t\to a$

Then $\lim_{t\to a}\frac {f(t)}{g(t)}=A$

**Proof:** Let $\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}=A+\phi(t)$, where $\phi (t)\to 0$ as $t\to a$. 
Let's apply Mean value theorem on $[x,y]\subset (a,b)$ to get a $t_{xy}\in (x,y)$ (let's use $t$ instead for brevity) such that $$
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{g(x)-g(y)}=\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}=A+\phi(t)\tag 3$$
Supposing that $(1)$ is true, taking $\lim x\to a$ in $(3)$ to get: $$
\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}=A+\phi(t_{ay})\tag 4$$
Now taking $\lim y\to a$ on both sides of $(4)$ to get: $$
\lim_{y\to a} \frac {f(y)}{g(y)}=A \tag 5$$
So part $1$ is complete.

Supposing that $(2)$ is true, then there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $g(x)\gt \max\{g(y),0\}$ on $[x,y]\subset (a,a+\delta)$ and so by $(3)$, we get: 
 $$
f(x)-f(y)=(A+\phi(t))(g(x)-g(y))\implies \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(y)}{g(x)}=(A+\phi(t))(1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)})\tag 6 $$
Taking $x\to a$ followed by $y\to a$ on both sides gives $(5)$ again. Note that here: $a,b$ can be in extended reals also. This proves the theorem.

Comment: Looks okay to me as far as I can see.

Comment: I have some doubts. Just after (3) I think you mean $x\to a$ (typo), but then you are assuming (I think) that as $x\to a$ we get that $t_{xy}$ converges to something you call $t_{ay}$ - I don't see this esp as $t_{ay}$ isn't defined as $a$ is outside the domain of everything in the question. Even if this is patchable I have doubts when you apply the (Cauchy)MVT to get (3), you need to be sure that the denominator is non-zero before you write the LHS of (3): you'll need the hypothesis $g'\not=0$ and the MVT to justify this.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: I did mean $x\to a$. Please note that $t_{ay}\in (a,y)$ by MVT. It doesn’t matter whether a is outside domain. Please note that I can apply MVT on (a,b) if end limits exist (This can be proven). About denominator being zero: noted. I should have clarified that.

Comment: To resolve the denominator 0 issue I can use the argument just after $(5)$ . I think that should repair the proof. @ancientmathematician.

Comment: Good, I am just saying you should justify these steps.

Comment: You are left with this slight puzzle: are you sure that as $x\to a$ we get $t_{xy}\to t_{ay}$? [I am not because the choice of $t_{xy}$ isn't unique.] But this is avoided if at the very outset you just apply the CMVT to the interval $(a,y)$ (with proper justification of course).

Comment: Thanks a lot @ancientmathematician for your kind review and very helpful suggestions. I hope rest everything is conceptually clear? :)

Comment: I think that it is now all going to be OK.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: Yes sure. Let me explain: Suppose that end limit exists at a for a function defined on $(a, b]$ then if $h$ is differentiable on (a,b) and continuous on (a,b] then there exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $h’(c)=0$. This is called generalised mean value theorem. It can be proven by applying LMVT to $g(x)=h(x) $ on (a,b] and $g(a)= \lim _{x\to a^+} h(x)$